# Disable ScrollTo animation depending on URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

My frontpage menu navigation smoothly scrolls the content and changes url hash depending on page section. E.g. www.example.com/#projects

Would it be possible to use some symbol within the external link to my website to turn of the frontpage animation and go to the desired section instantly on page load while in general leaving the animation effect working?

E.g. www.example.com/#projects@

```
$('.top-menu ul li a').bind('click',function(e){
        var ref = $(this).attr('href')
        ref = ref.split('#');
        var s_to = $('#scope-'+ref[ref.length-1])
        $(document).scrollTo(
            s_to,
            scrollSpeed,
            {
                "offset":{"top": -50 },
                'easing':'easeInOutQuad',
                'onAfter':function(){
                    window.location.hash = ref[ref.length-1];   
                }
            }
        );
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: instead of using another url i would check if the host of document.refferer is not the host of your app

Comment: If this only for external links I think @johnSmith has a good answer..

Comment: just do > (document.referrer.indexOf(document.location.host)>-1)

Comment: I need this in internal pages of my website. For example I have a new page "Contact" and within it - a menu item that links to frontpage's "Projects" section. So I guess it would be the same host?